# Checking if a machine_name exists or not

Tags: forms, 8, entities

My EntityForm has a field where

```
  '#machine_name' => array(
    'exists' => array($this, 'load'),
```

To check the validation of this, I wanted to know about writing the function `load()` in my `EntityListBuilder` to check its validation.

A way around would be to use `ctools`:

```
ctools_include('export');
$result = ctools_export_load_object('module_entityname', 'names', array($field_id));
```

However, I wanted to avoid using `ctools`. 
Are there any Drupal 8 APIs available to check the validation of `#machine_name`?

Comment: `machine_name` elements are already validated by [`form_validate_machine_name ()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21form.inc/function/form_validate_machine_name/8)...have I missed what you're trying to do? Or are you looking for a generic entity_exists type callback you can use in place of your own exists function?

Comment: @Clive: So that means, it should just be `'#machine_name' => array('exists' => array($this)`? I'm unable to find any relevant docs about the second parameter passed in the array.

Comment: Sorry if I'm still misunderstanding, but if I'm not then you don't need to implement a new method for this, you can use your entity controller's load method. So it would be `'exists' => '\Drupal\mymodule\Entity\MyEntity::load'`

Comment: @Clive: that was my basic doubt. I'm unable to code the `load` function. The Entity examples given on Drupal.org are without any implementation of `load` functions.

Comment: No need to implement anything unless you need to change the default behaviour of loading by ID, `load()` is inherited from [`Entity::load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3Aload/8) so it's already available

Comment: @Clive: So I just add the namespace `use Drupal\Core\Entity` in `myentityForm` and do `'#machine_name' => array(
    'exists' => array($this, 'load'),` and things will be taken care of without any overriding `load()` method?

Comment: Not quite, I've put an answer in hope that clears it up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `exists` key wants a [callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) that it can test for boolean true/false. The machine name to test will be passed as the first (and only) argument to that callback.

Since your entity class (not the list builder class) already has a load method, inherited from [`Entity::load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3Aload/8), which accepts an ID and returns either an entity object or a null/false value, you can (and probably should) use that.

So, assuming your entity is defined as `\Drupal\mymodule\Entity\MyEntity`, you would use the following:

```
'#machine_name' => array(
  'exists' => '\Drupal\mymodule\Entity\MyEntity::load',
```

Exactly the same method is used in the [`CommentTypeForm`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!comment!src!CommentTypeForm.php/8?order=title&sort=desc), and probably others:

```
$form['id'] = array(
  '#type' => 'machine_name',
  '#default_value' => $comment_type->id(),
  '#machine_name' => array(
    'exists' => '\Drupal\comment\Entity\CommentType::load',
  ),
  '#maxlength' => EntityTypeInterface::BUNDLE_MAX_LENGTH,
  '#disabled' => !$comment_type->isNew(),
);
```

Comment: @xan is that content entity or config entity? I trying this for content entity and it is not working. I'm trying to port PET module.